# Visual Workflow - getting field values from sObject into a flow field

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm absolutely not clear on this so I'm gonna go ahead and ask:  Can I - when using a flow - get the field values for a dropdown value from a sObject variable, like you can when using a Visualforce page bound to an sObject?

My object in question contains quite a few picklists with a fair amount of values in them.  The idea is to create a wizard-driven interface using VWF to create records.

I'd rather not maintain picklist values in two places ( in the flow & in the field values themselves) so if this isn't possible I'll just go with vanilla Apex+Visualforce instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you still cannot get picklist values in a flow, without code/maintaing both places. There is an idea that can be voted up [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hqtrAAA). There is also a plugin available [here](https://github.com/rajasGit/FlowPicklistSync).

Comment: Argh, that explains a lot.  Thanks for those links,  SF StackExchange to the rescue!  I'm going to go with Apex+Visualforce based solution instead.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well, one other suggestion was to query the existing values and use those, but that only works if all options have been used at some point.